# newtx option otfmath: what's the point?

Tags: newtxmath, newtx, newtxtext

The `otfmath` option to the `newtx` package (or, equivalently, that option to the `newtxtext` package along with `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, when used under a Unicode engine), "supports an arbitrary, user-selected OTF math font along with `TeXGyreTermesX` for text" [from newtxdoc.pdf, Section 2.1]. The math font is then selected by a `\setmathfont{...}[...]` command.

What would be accomplished by using that option: which features and other options of `newtx` are preserved that would otherwise have force if one used `newtx` either with OTF text but Type 1 math or else with Type 1 for both text and math?

Comment: I only looked quickly, but I think it partly makes sure enabled options are compatible. For example, it overrides some options if you try to pick incompatible ones. So it will use `newtxtext` and `fontspec` regardless because those are the only compatible packages, for example. So I think it isn't a question of what options are preserved but rather of which options are disabled.